# GEE: Deciduous vs. Coniferous trees

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to isolate deciduous and coniferous trees using GEE. I don't have the ground truths.

I was advised to do this using monthly NDVI maps. But I don't know which characteristics in the map would show that the respective trees are deciduous or coniferous.
How do we record the monthly change in values that would indicate that the corresponding pixels are coniferous or deciduous trees?

Comment: You can look at this paper: Estimation of the Conifer-Broadleaf Ratio in Mixed Forests Based on Time-Series Data https://www.researchgate.net/publication/355908287_Estimation_of_the_Conifer-Broadleaf_Ratio_in_Mixed_Forests_Based_on_Time-Series_Data  it seems that conifers have a more constant value, while deciduous have a peak in a summer and a low in winter. It might depend on which part of the globe you want to study though, as some trees in tropical areas lose their leaves in the dry season (but there isn't really a winter)

Comment: @XaC In this paper field samples were used.

Comment: Do a multi-temporal classification using NDVI or other index related to forests. Deciduous should have lower veg. index value during winter

Comment: @aldo_tapia So, I should see the monthly change and if it is changing then I should state that those pixels are deciduous, right? Should I see the maps manually or is there an automatic method through which I can see the change?

Comment: The easiest approach is to compute NDVI in a summer date and a winter date, then compute the difference between the two dates. A robust approach is to take samples manually, train an ANN/RF/SVM model and get a classification map

Comment: @aldo_tapia It's a great approach. Thank you! I'll try it out.